# can paypal integration be used for a shopping cart app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, paypal, app-store

my project involves money transaction and selling of physical goods just like amazon,flipkart etc..and  is it possible to sell  physical goods  by using a paypal API and also
with my reference in other questions i  was about to get some conclusions

App store will reject apps with paypal integration and they will accept only when there is involvement of charity,and donation
Appstore  require 30 % of revenue from the app if its transferring money through the app

is there any way  which should be most accurate to integrate the paypal within the app,avoiding the rejection?

Comment: And this is why I don't support iPhones. Bloody scams :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you shouldnt use the payment methods for accessing your app, for example: Remove ads, get extra levels, etc., Its because you are trying to cut that 30% pay to apple. So in this case you must use in-app purchases.

But you can use the payment methods for shopping, donation, charity, etc.